# How to plot this function in matlab

Tags: matlab

The problem is how to plot the below equation in discrete form:

> g=(1-exp(-1i*pi*k))/(1-exp(-1i*pi*k/50)) where k ranges from -300 to 300

When I execute the program I always get the following error:

> "Attempted to access (-299); index must be a positive integer or logical."

I don't really know what it means, I tried to exclude the even value of pi but still the same problem. I need a hand here please.

Comment: Post the (relevant part of) the program you talk about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
clear all
k = -300:300;
g = (1-exp(-1i*pi*k))./(1-exp(-1i*pi*k/50));
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(k,real(g))
ylabel('real(g)')
xlabel('k')
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(k,imag(g))
ylabel('imag(g)')
xlabel('k')
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(g)
xlabel('real(g)')
ylabel('imag(g)')
```

I'm affraid you could have overriden exp and this caused a problem

Comment: It worked, the equation is of fourier series coefficient of certain signal, it more clear when plotted as with a command stem (k, abs(g)). Thanks